# Concentration of U-statistics for exchangable distributions (and the unbounded case)

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration

Consider the following so-called $U$-statistic of order 2: $$U = \frac1{\binom{m}{2}} \sum_{i < j} h(w_i,w_j)$$ where $w_1,\dots,w_m$ are IID from some distribution and $h$ is symmetric. If $|h(w_1,w_2)| \le B$ a.s., then a classical result gives the following concentration inequality:
\begin{align}
   \mathbb P( | U - \mathbb E U| \ge t) \le 2 \exp(- m t^2 /(8B^2)).
\end{align}
(Maybe there are better constants known here.)

I have the following two questions:

- It seems to me that this immediately generalizes to the case where $(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ has an exchangeable distribution, due to **de Finetti**'s theorem saying that any such distribution is a result of a mixture of IID ones. More precisely, there is a random measure $G$, such that conditional on $G$, $w_1,\dots,w_n$ are IID draws from $G$. By conditioning on $G$, using the inequality above for the IID case, and then taking expectations, we get the result for the exchangeable case. Is this argument correct?
- What is the state of the art in terms of concentration bounds for such $U$-statistics, esp in the case where $h$ is not bounded? Are there clear generalization known, esp. for the exchangable case? The above argument seems to rely on boundedness of $h$ in a critical way.

EDIT: I should say that for the first point, it might be that we have to assume $h$ to be surely bounded (?)

EDIT: As was pointed out, the argument in point one is flawed. In the hindsight, one needs extra conditions. The case where $w_1=w_2=\dots=w_m$ is an example of an exchangeable distribution for which the concentration (with $m$ in the exponent) need not hold.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the conclusion will hold for a general exchangeable sequence. In a more general case, you have to assume that U-statistics itself are not degenerated ($w_i\neq w_j$ for $i\neq j$) and the concentration bound is still not so good as shown in [Arcones].

However, for the case where exchangeable pairs exists (like independent yet not necessarily identical), [Lester Mackey et.al] Coro 5.2. might be what you want.

I think the following paper [Matrix Concentration Inequalities via the Method
of Exchangeable Pairs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6002.pdf) is what you want to/what you should read. Instead of considering exchangeable random variables, the usual way of thinking independence, which started by C.Stein ([Stein's original paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200514239)), is to consider independent pairs of random variables. This is also natural from a categorical view since we can only discuss the commutativity of one diagram (commutativity of diagrams is equivalent to exchangeability if we formalized the category appropriately, see [Category-theoretic structure for conditional independence](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/als/Talks/cambridge14.pdf).)

The definition given in [Lester Mackey et.al] is:

> Let $Z$ and $Z′$ be random variables taking values in a Polish space
>   $\mathcal{Z}$. We say that $(Z, Z′)$ is an exchangeable pair if it has
>   the same distribution as $(Z′,Z)$. In particular, $Z$ and $Z′$ must
>   share the same distribution.

[Arcones] Arcones, Miguel A. "A Bernstein-type inequality for U-statistics and U-processes." Statistics & probability letters 22.3 (1995): 239-247.

[Lester Mackey et.al] Mackey, Lester, et al. "Matrix concentration inequalities via the method of exchangeable pairs." The Annals of Probability 42.3 (2014): 906-945. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6002.pdf

Comment: Please feel free to ask more, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood.

But it seems that for the first point, your proof does not work in general since there will be a $\mathbb{E}(U|G)$ and not $\mathbb{E}(U)$. And from then I do not see how to conclude.

Comment: You are right! I just realized that and I was about to make an edit. I am still going to keep it open, in case someone knows about a result in the exchangeable case.

Comment: it remains an interesting question indeed